# What does this expression means: bool(__args...)

Tags: c++, stl

I just stumbled around in the STL for C++ and found a quite surprising exception in the `vector` header.
Cleaned up from some unnecessary junk it boils down to this:
(This snippets could be found in the `vector` class within the STL `vector` header)

```cpp
template<typename... _Args>
reference emplace_back(_Args&&... __args) {
    push_back(bool(__args...));
    return back();
}

void push_back(bool __x) {
    if (this->_M_impl._M_finish._M_p != this->_M_impl._M_end_addr())
        *this->_M_impl._M_finish++ = __x;
    else
         _M_insert_aux(end(), __x);
}
```

As already outlined in the title, I'm quite surprised by the `bool(__args...)` expression which makes no sense for me at all.
I hope somebody could bring light into the darkness and help me out.

#### Edit: Answered, I was a bit lazy

Solution found, I was a bit lazy.
I used my IDEs method resolver to jump to the declaration.
But sadly it directed me to the `stl_bvector.h` header and the given method above.
Since it seems that this header only handles the implementation for `std::vector<bool>` the code makes much more sense.

Comment: It looks like you also removed some necessary junk, including the context. It would also help if you mentioned which implementation this is.

Comment: Oh well I should name the class ofc, its the vector impl. in the STL.  
Edit: I've updated the post, but I think that knowing more context really helps to get a feeling whats going on here ;)

Comment: It is pretty obviously the `vector<bool>`specialization.

Comment: If *you* think that knowing more context helps, imagine how the rest of us feel. Please say which implementation this is (name and version) and include the line numbers.

Comment: yeahr  just wanted to do that and then I noticed my error. I'm sorry, but I just looked that suff already 20 mins up and was quite sure I got everything. NVM thanks for your time anyways ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're checking the implementation of `std::vector<bool>`.

`bool(__args...)` is constructing a temporary `bool` from the parameter pack `__args...` (which is expanded into comma-separated expressions), then the temporary `bool` is passed to the `push_back(bool)`.

Comment: I thought so as well, but this is the general implementation.  
So its also equal for `std::vector<std::string>`. I'm also not seeing any specialisation for other types)

Comment: @WolverinDEV it is not, if you mean libstdc++. The code you have specified is for bool specialization.

Comment: @WolverinDEV It won't make sense for general `std::vector` to have a member function `push_back(bool)`; so...

Comment: I thought so either thats why I asked :D   
But I may found the issue... I relied too much oin the IDEs method resolver. It actiually sends me to `std_bvector.h` which is the possible impl for `std::vector<bool>`